# How to run tests with Arquillian IN_CONTAINER mode with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I'm in the middle of reading EJB 3, second edition by manning and am having a tough time running tests on the source in IntelliJ

**Test is:**
Full Source can be found [here](http://action-bazaar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/chapter2/src/test/java/com/actionbazaar/buslogic/ItemServiceTest.java):

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@Run(RunModeType.IN_CONTAINER)
....
.....
    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "foo.jar").addClasses(OrderProcessor.class,
                OrderProcessorBean.class,
                ItemService.class,
                ItemServiceBean.class, Bid.class, Bidder.class, Item.class).addManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", ArchivePaths.create("persistence.xml"));
    }
```

**persistence.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="users" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>jdbc/chapter2</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error while running test is:**

```
WARNING: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
```

**UPDATE**

domain.xml is located [here](http://action-bazaar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/chapter2/src/test/resources/domain.xml):

From the error it seems like a database connection could not be established. However, I'm not sure why it isn't able to connect to the in memory derby database. since the domain.xml has the `create=true` property, the db should simply be created.

Answer (score 0):

> From the error it seems like a database connection could not be established. However, I'm not sure which database is it trying to connect to. I have no database running on my system for this.

```
Do I need to have a database running specifically or will the test run a database on it's own?
If so, which one?
```

The test should be trying to connect to an in-memory derby database instance as configured in [/test/resources/glassfish/config/domain.xml](http://action-bazaar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/chapter2/src/test/resources/glassfish/config/domain.xml), so I don't think you need any further setup.

[Brian's comments at this arquillian doc](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoISetupADataSourceInEmbeddedGlassFishWhenUsingArquillian) suggest a couple of changes in arquillian.xml. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. I failed to look at the `domain.xml` still however, I get the same error even with adding the namespace.